# How does the international community differentiate between a "rights activist" and a separatist?

Tags: human-rights, freedom-of-speech

This has been my personal observation for a long time that in some countries, when the government says that they are cracking down on separatism, the so-called "free world" come forward and designate those separatist individuals or groups(who are running a separatist movement in the disguise of human rights activism by obtaining foreign funds) with adjectives like " rights activist", "civil society", etc. and say that the " human rights situation is bad" in that particular country and "the government is suppressing freedom of speech."

How does the "free world" differentiate between "separatism" and "rights movement"? How do they differentiate between a separatist leader/activist and a rights activist?

Here are my examples:

1. I can recall the anarchy(e.g. [Hong Kong Protest: Rioters Beat Up Innocent Civilian](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fr_wb8PzK5U), [Female HONG KONG protester beat up innocent grandpa](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MFLvKdonoFU)) in Hong Kong was appreciated and cheered by the free world, on the other hand, white house occupation/invasion was condemned.
2. Recently France introduced an [anti-separatism bill](https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2020/12/9/france-reveals-details-of-controversial-separatism-bill) in the parliament.

Here are my concerns:

1. [Gulalai Ismail: Activist in hiding flees Pakistan for the US](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-49765178) - This lady [received funds from a hostile government](https://www.thenews.com.pk/print/500505-two-ngos-head-charged-with-terror-financing) to Pakistan to manufacture "Pashtun rights"-issue through a movement called PTM. One of its prominent leaders, Manzoor Pashteen, received training from the Afghan government.
2. Pakistani separatists [Brahumdagh Bugti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahumdagh_Bugti) and [Hyrbyair Marri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyrbyair_Marri) are enjoying asylum in Switzerland and the UK respectively.
3. [Why is the Pakistani government cracking down on NGOs?](https://amp.dw.com/en/why-is-the-pakistani-government-cracking-down-on-ngos/a-56537755) - A German media house says that Pakistan is cracking down on NGOs and "civil society" when there are concrete proofs that the CIA used Pakistani NGOs to implement their own agenda in Pakistan.

**Hulk** brought up Catalonia's separatism issue. I would like to remind him that Scotland and Catalonia are parts of the free world. So, the free world is saying nothing decisive in those cases. So, those cases are yielding mixed feelings.

Answer (score 10):

> How does the "free world" differentiate between "separatism" and "rights movement"? How do they differentiate between a separatist leader/activist and a rights activist?

Those things can overlap, so in some cases they *don't*.

A separatist wants to create a new country from a part of an existing country. A rights activist wants (more) protected freedoms.

If someone both thinks their government is restricting their freedoms, and also wants to create a new country from a part of their existing country, they are a "rights activist" and a "separatist".

Comment: As an example, the SNP is a political party in the UK that campaigns for an independent Scotland. They are separatists, and are happy to be called that. They don't contend that the UK government is suppressing any of their human rights, and afaict no one else contends that. They are not rights activists w.r.t. Scottish independence (some members of the SNP might be be activists for other rights movements, but that is unconnected to the SNP as a political organisation)

Comment: Indeed, it's quite possible for separatist movements to want considerable less in the way of rights - or at least what most in the West would consider rights.  Consider ISIS, for example.

Answer (score 4):

This is not a matter of the “free world”, this is basic terminology. The only reason to keep it here instead of https://english.stackexchange.com/ is because the OP put a political spin on it which needs to be dispelled.

Unlike traitors vs revolutionary or freedom fighters vs terrorist, neither  "separatist movement" or "rights movement" change based upon a historical or political perspective.  Both are simple descriptive terms like “a hammer” that refer to a political activity. A separatist movement wants to split a political unit, and a rights movements wants to increase what is considered the rights of some group (invariably at the expense of reducing at least the implicit rights of another group).

An organization can be both, just as a multi-tool that is both a hammer and a screwdriver can exist.

The free world isn’t invariably for either, although it’s bias will tend to be in favor of rights movements, assuming that everyone wants the same rights (stupid of them to be sure, as such movements frequently start a reactionary rights movements which is the opposite of what they desire).  There is also tendency to favorably view separatist movements on a rights basis (eg too assume that there would not be a separatist movements if there was no need for a rights movement that they approve of).

But regardless of ones political opinions, it should be easy to say whether a group or individual was one or the other or both.  Emperor Diocletian was a separatist, so was George Washington.

Answer (score 2):

I will say one thing that may help your question. Do not confuse western media (like DW in the link) and western governments.

I think the best example everybody understands here would be Tibet. Here all governments agree it is China, they just never say anything about it to the media. And most media show support to Tibet.

There are so many seperatists in the world and you question uses Pakistan as example. If you ask any western government how they see e.g. the movement in Balochistan then all will say that is Pakistan, and not something seperate, so the story about DW shutting down NGO cannot just be simplified to beeing against Pakistan.

Comment: *e.g. the movement in Balochistan then all will say that is Pakistan* --- Here is the difference, the free world sees Balochistan as a human rights disaster. Pakistan sees it as **[a foreign hand in the play](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kulbhushan_Jadhav)**. It seems like the "free world" is choosing the narrative from India because India is their bigger trading partner.

Comment: What's _"DW"_?  You use it twice without any antecedent or definition.

Comment: @Flydog57I think "DW" is "Deutsche Welle" and the last sentence is meant to be "DW story about..." the fourth link in the question.

Comment: @user366312 a situation can be *both* triggered by foreign influence *and* a human rights desaster at the same time. And even if we don't agree with goals of a certain group, we can still criticize the way the government deals with it.

Answer (score -1):

Western governments and societies **think they learned** from the European experience that ethnic or religiously defined homelands are **bad**. Such groups never have exact boundaries, and trying to unite all of one group in one state (or trying to create a new state for one group) creates oppressed minorities, resentment, war, and chaos. Look what the attempt to create one country for all Germans did.

They also **think they learned** that the way to keep disparate groups happy within an unified state is to guarantee civil and human rights for all and to strengthen what is termed **civil socity**.

So a *separatist* is seen as a bad thing, unless fighting for independence from what is perceived as unjust hegemony (perceived by western governments and societies, that is).

Someone who speaks out for freedom of the press gets a positive image unless there are special circumstances.

Someone who speaks out for independence gets a negative image unless there are special circumstances.

Comment: I don't think the western viewpoint treats "separatist" as particularly good *or* bad in the abstract.

Comment: @Caleth, if there is a historically defined state trying to regain autonomy, perhaps. But in general that's associated with upheaval and that causes refugees.

Comment: What "one country for all Germans did"?  Seems to have worked pretty well, whether you mean 19th century German unification, or the reunification of East & West Germany.

Comment: @jamesqf, I was thinking about the Nazi idea to conquer any territory with any Germans in it, and then some. Österreich. Sudetenland.

Comment: @o.m.: Wasn't aware that the Nazis were all that interested in limiting their conquests to areas with Germans (or German-speaking people).  France, Poland, Norway, Russia... not a lot of German speakers in those places.  OTOH Switzerland has a lot of German speakers, but wasn't invaded.

Comment: @jamesqf, take a look at the propaganda around 1937, 38, 39. Yes, Switzerland wasn't invaded. Danzig. The Polish Corridor. and so on.

Comment: @jamesqf the Großgermanisches Reich wasn't premised on being German but rather Germanic. It wasn't intended to include much of France. In Poland and Russia (both of which did have many German speakers at the time) the Nazis planned to elevate local German populations, "Germanize" "middling" populations, and kill or expel the Slavs. All of continental Scandinavia was considered Germanic and therefore included, and while they wanted the further islands they recognized it might be difficult to take them. Nazis did want to integrate German Switzerland into Germany but Barbarossa took precedent.

Comment: @Hulk, of course there is no unified opinion. You write the view may have a majority -- unanimity on such an issue is unlikely.

Comment: @gormadoc:  Of course the Nazis had those racial superiority theories, but I think you are, perhaps understandably, thinking that Germanic and Aryan are synonymous, though they're rather different.  E.g. a German Jew was still a member of an inferior non-Aryan race, while non-Germanic scandanavians were still Aryan.